# Could not connect to Azure remote computer exception after deploy

Tags: exception, azure, deployment, visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration

I have a MVC5 internet application using EF6 and am having trouble deploying to Azure. I have deployed successfully in the past, to the same url, the only difference is that I am now using a BizSpark account.

I am using continious integration and am deploying from Visual Studio Online.

Here is the error message:

```
Exception Message: Could not connect to the remote computer ("canfindlocation.scm.azurewebsites.net"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE. (type DeploymentDetailedException)
```

I have had a look at the web resource, and here is the description:

```
ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE
Diagnosis - Web Management Service or Remote Agent is not installed or unreachable on the remote computer.
Resolution - Verify that Remote Agent Service or Web Management Service are started on the remote computer, depending on which one you are connecting to. You can do a "net start wmsvc & net start msdepsvc" on the remote computer to ensure these services are started. Also, ensure that a firewall is not interrupting communications with the destination.
```

Can I please have some help to get this working?

Thanks in advance